# cProfile inside a nested function

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to profile a nested function using `cProfile.run`. I understand that perhaps `cProfile` isn't running at the same scope as where I am calling it, but I'm not quite sure what the idiomatic way to achieve this is. Here's an MVCE:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        # do something here
        return 1
    cProfile.run('bar()')
```

Gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cProfile.runctx`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#profile.runctx):

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        # do something here
        return 1
    cProfile.runctx('bar()', None, locals=locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cProfile.run

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        # do something here
        return 1
    cProfile.run(bar.__code__)
```